# jquery .attr('alt','logo').css('display','none') not working !

Tags: jquery-selectors, attributes

I have the three following lines and the first two line gets all the images on the document and hides all, but then when I add the third line shows all the images.

What I need its to hide only the images with the attribute alt=minimize and alt=maximize but for some reason hides all the images.

```
$('img').attr('alt', 'minimize').css("display","none");
$('img').attr('alt', 'maximize').css("display","none");


$('img').attr('alt', 'logo').css("display","inline");
```

I am using IE7, but it should be compatible with IE6 and IE8.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rephrase "to taking into account the attribute alt.", I don't know what you are getting at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking you are not using the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function correctly, might you be looking for the [attribute equals selector?](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('img[alt=minimize]').css("display","none");
```

What you did with your code was,

1. Select all images
2. Change their alt attribute to `'minimize'`
3. Hide them
4. Select all images
5. Change their alt attribute to `'maximize'`
6. Hide them
7. Select all images
8. Change their alt attribute to `'logo'`
9. Hide them

Comment: Thanks for so quick reply, and detailed answer. +1

Comment: @JimMichaels The question is about jQuery, so no.

Answer (score 2):

what you do: you take every `img` in document and set `alt` to `logo` and then set `display: inline;`.

Note, that `attr('alt',string)` doesn't filter all images to those with `alt=string`, but rather sets `alt` attribute to `string` on all images.

What you want to use is this:

```
$('img[alt="minimize"]').css...
$('img[alt="maximize"]').css...

$('img[alt="logo"]').css...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know what I was doing. Thanks for so quick reply. +1

Answer (score 1):

In the call $('img').attr('alt', 'logo').css("display","inline"); the "attr" doesen't filter the set of dom elements You catch with $("img").

If you want to hide everithing but not the image with the attribute 'alt' = 'logo' I think You can:

give it an Id of logo and then calling: $("img").not("#logo").hide()

from the jquery website:

> hide():
>
> The matched elements will be hidden
> immediately, with no animation. This
> is roughly equivalent to calling
> .css('display', 'none'), except that
> the value of the display property is
> saved in jQuery's data cache so that
> display can later be restored to its
> initial value. If an element has a
> display value of inline, then is
> hidden and shown, it will once again
> be displayed inline.

and

> attr( attributeName )
> Returns: String
>
> Description: Get the value of an
> attribute for the first element in the
> set of matched elements.

If instead you want to hide all the maximize and minimize images (both share the "imize" part of the attribute):
$(parentElement).find("img[@attr $= '*imize']").hide()

Answer (score 0):

OP is referring to

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#attr

alt I *think* is simply a string type, not "logo" whatever that is, that is not a data type.
try that.  in fact, you can look up alt in the html5 img

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-img-element.html#the-img-element

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-img-element.html#attr-img-alt

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-img-element.html#alt

(in order of reference clicking, last one is the target)

even if this isn't the exact answer (it should be), it should be a step in the right direction.

I am actually trying myself to figure out how to reference a css property within css with attr() - it's mentioned within the top URL. if I had my druthers, I could be using css calc() along with it, but that's draft.  maybe I can get it to work...